# animation in show hide button

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have a problem with my simple fuction. I have a funtion to show more content or less, and it working fine but I don't know how I can add simple animation to my exist function like fade-in fade-out

```
this.showMore = ko.observable(false);
this.toggleShowMore = function () {
  this.showMore(!this.showMore());
};
```

and data bind in html

```
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-info" data-bind='click: toggleShowMore '>More data</button>
```

this code working correct but I don't know how to add animation.
This is my first steps in knokout so I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: Try the answer from this previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979695/how-to-combine-ko-js-and-jquery-to-fade-in-dynamically-bound-dom-objects

Comment: Thank you Jason - I tried and doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the custom bindings. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html  I pretty much copied and pasted the example below I just changed it to fade instead of slide.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.slideVisible = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        // First get the latest data that we're bound to
        var value = valueAccessor();
 
        // Next, whether or not the supplied model property is observable, get its current value
        var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);
 
        // Grab some more data from another binding property
        var duration = allBindings.get('fadeDuration') || 400; // 400ms is default duration unless otherwise specified
 
        // Now manipulate the DOM element
        if (valueUnwrapped == true)
            $(element).fadeIn(duration); // Make the element visible
        else
            $(element).fadeOut(duration);   // Make the element invisible
    }
};

 var viewModel = {
        giftWrap: ko.observable(true)
    };
   viewModel.togglegiftWrap = function() {
      viewModel.giftWrap(!viewModel.giftWrap())
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="slideVisible: giftWrap, fadeDuration:600">You have selected the option</div>
<button class="" data-bind="click: togglegiftWrap">More info</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan it is a good start and nice example, but now I have a problem with this function, on start content is show (my must by hidden), when I click on button I don't see my content again, just working only once

Comment: you changed the checkbox to a button so you need an onclick event to toggle the value. I changed edited the answer

Comment: fantastic! this is it. Thank you so much for a help.

Comment: PS Bryan it is possible creating a funtion to show only one element (just clicked) and hide all without this one eg. I have 10 buttons when I click on first button I see animation content etc, now I click on second button and I see content for second button but content from first buttom is still active (have lower z-index and is not visible but is still there), And my question is can I do a function to show content for clicked button and hide rest? It is possible?

Comment: so if I am reading correctly you want the button group to behave like a radio button group. so only one is active at a time? so maybe use the checked binding with a radio button like this  http://jsfiddle.net/47d6r/391/  if that is what your are after you can style your radio buttons to look like buttons. check out bootstrap toggle buttons for an example

Comment: here is the same fiddle but it delays the fade in until fade out is complete http://jsfiddle.net/47d6r/392/

Comment: yes you almost understand me correct, I have a 6 buttons in list, my data on load is hidden. When I click on button i will be see data in content example more information what is on this street. But data on load is hidden and is showing only when you click on button. Now I dont have a fuction to show only active/clicked button and hidding rest data. And in my project I dont use radio but a links in list.